# Shaky scale animation

Tags: javascript, css

I am doing little mosaic (if i can call it like that). I am changing scale and opacity based on position mouse and the center of the picture/div.

I am calculating the distance via vektors with

```
 function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offsetLeft + (elem.offsetWidth / 2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offsetTop + (elem.offsetHeight / 2)), 2)));
    }
```

and im looping throught the divs/pictures and if the distance is smaller than 100 , it calculates its opacity/scale.

But i came to a problem , where animation of changing opacity/scale is little bit shakky. It seems like its hesitating if it should do something.

Demo = http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/x9fpv8pb/5/

Is there any way or shortcut how to fix that as i called it shakking or hesitating?

Comment: I think you're doing too many calls, but I'm checking it out atm :)

Comment: I got it a bit better already, but still not 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/x9fpv8pb/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is the `-webkit-transition` rule in your CSS. If you try to transition your elements with CSS and change the value 60 times a second with JS, it will flicker.

Also, you probably shouldn't add an event listener to every single element. This will cause unnecessary operations. Instead, you can add one on their parent (I added it to the `nav`).

There was some room for optimizing also, which further smoothens out the transition. Here's the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/x9fpv8pb/16/

Comment: Thats what i wanted, but just to add , if i put mousemove on nav element , and i move mouse in the nav space where divs arent located (empty space) it scales whole nav

Comment: Doesn't for me - at least not in my fiddle. And I don't see how it could. What browser are you using? _Edit:_ I tried it on ff/ie/chrome and worked perfectly on all - are you getting that error in my fiddle some other code you've made modifications to?

Comment: i have that bug in every fiddle with that code if i set mousemove on nav , thats the reason i set it on each element it doesnt even throw an error.